# Read .asc data and .dat in Python for project

Tags: python

I have been trying to find a way to read data I found from:

https://daac.ornl.gov/cgi-bin/dsviewer.pl?ds_id=1028

I was under the wrong impression I could treat ASC as a netCDF and found that out very quickly. Is there a way for me to read the data and put it into arrays that I can turn into graphs?

I'm trying to read the sediment flux of different rivers throughout the years and make a change over time graph at the least.

There are two types of files I could use, one is a .dat and the other is a .asc; any syntax for being able to read the data without seeing lines of "NAN" or "-999".

I have been trying to find a way to read data I found from:

https://daac.ornl.gov/cgi-bin/dsviewer.pl?ds_id=1028

I was under the wrong impression I could treat ASC as a netCDF and found that out very quickly. Is there a way for me to read the data and put it into arrays that I can turn into graphs?

I'm trying to read the sediment flux of different rivers throughout the years and make a change over time graph at the least.

There are two types of files I could use, one is a .dat and the other is a .asc; any syntax for being able to read the data without seeing lines of "NAN" or "-999".

When using code for data

The code I used for the asc.

```
np.loadtxt('ocean_flux_tss_1d_map.asc', skiprows = 6)
```

I get this back. This is the map in data form, it has a shape of (180, 360) and I need to find a way to load the map in python. Is there any code for that? Is there an alternative way I need to load the data to accomplish this?

```
[[-99. -99. -99. ... -99. -99. -99.]
 [-99. -99. -99. ... -99. -99. -99.]
 [-99. -99. -99. ... -99. -99. -99.]
 ...
 [-88. -88. -88. ... -88. -88. -88.]
 [-88. -88. -88. ... -88. -88. -88.]
 [-88. -88. -88. ... -88. -88. -88.]]
```

Comment: We can't really help you, because that site will only allow downloads if one has an account.  If you want to post a hex dump of the first section of the file, maybe we can offer advice.

Comment: Ooo, how can i do that???

Comment: If you're on Linux or MacOS, `hexdump -C file.xxx | head -50 > save.txt`.  If you're on WIndows, there are no built-in tools, although there are some you could download.  If you can store the file in a neutral location, I could look at it.

Comment: I used this code:                                                                                                     with open('/home/srowpie/SrowFinProj/Datas/ocean_flux_tss_2d.dat', 'rb') as f:
    data = f.read()                                                                                                              and I printed it, would you like to see the printed version of it, or would you prefer I use a third party medium?

Comment: If it's not too big, you can add it to your question.  Otherwise, you should probably use a service.

Comment: @TimRoberts I added part of the data to the question

Comment: Updated the thing, hopefully it is more helpful

Comment: You showed us the `dat`, but how is the `asc` different?'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't read in binary mode if you don't have to. The `.dat` files are plain text and look like this, which should be super easy to use. Just read them using

`with open('ocean_flux_tss_2d.dat', 'r') as f:`

```
-178.750,-77.0000,5.04768E-03,32128.7
-176.250,-77.0000,2.24318E-02,32128.7
-173.750,-77.0000,2.53902E-02,39113.5
-171.250,-77.0000,5.86083E-02,58934.0
-168.750,-77.0000,0.886519,179959.
-166.250,-77.0000,0.460672,692235.
-163.750,-77.0000,8.16516E-02,8815.86
-161.250,-77.0000,5.67409E-02,8815.86
-158.750,-77.0000,0.357408,46922.3
```

Or just load them into a pandas dataframe....

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("ocean_flux_co2_2d.dat", header=None)
print(df.head())
-------------------------------------------------------
        0     1         2         3
0 -178.75 -77.0  0.000003   32128.7
1 -176.25 -77.0  0.000599   32128.7
2 -173.75 -77.0  0.001649   39113.5
3 -171.25 -77.0  0.003838   58934.0
4 -168.75 -77.0  0.007192  179959.0
```

The `.asc` files are a text version of the images like this, it's doubtful you're going to make much sense of these without digging deeper into how these are made.

[image: .asc image]

All in all, it's never a bad idea to just try opening your files in a plain text editor. If it's actually binary data, you'll immediately know by the symbols everywhere...

Comment: Awesome, I am trying to figure out what I can still do with this data. Is there a way for me to make graphs of the sediment flux over time? Is this image from the data? and is there a way I can recreate this map?

Comment: I'd suggest reading through their `user guide` and `read_me`s for this information~

Comment: I see that with the .dat files I can create one of the maps with it. is there a function in panda or numpy that can create put the data on a map? I know how to make a map with contour lines. I am just unsure if there is a special process for this type of data?

Comment: Trying to slice the latitude and longitude data

Comment: What i am trying to get at is how do I then put this data into an array that I can slice? Sorry for all the questions